# Open list of an input element onclick

Tags: javascript, html, list, input

I have an INPUT element with the "`list`" property.

HTML code:

```
<input id="options" list="option" onclick="myExpand();" />
<datalist id="option">
  <option value="Option A" />
  <option value="Option B" />
</datalist>
```

The list will open only if I click on the right-side arrow.
Is there a way to open the list at "`onclick`" event with javascript?

Already tried with `ExpandSelect("option");` with no result.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can do this with your current code. The click is being used to enable text input via the keyboard (start typing after your click and you'll see).  Opening the list at that point might be confusing (and probably would confuse a screen reader) or annoying to the user if they know they want to type something else. I don't see a way in the DOM API that gets you at the popup that it shows, just to the `<datalist>`.

A second click does show the list as you want.

You could use a `<select>` element instead. That would open on click but won't let you type in other things. And you can't use a datalist with it.

You could use some other scheme to manage the popup. Create your own popup you show onclick. This would be a lot easier using some Javascript toolkit like JQuery.

Comment: Thank you Sir. you're right. By double click on input element set as "list", the dropdown appear correctly. It does the work I needed.